# How to actually get email DELIVERED past spam filters

Tags: email

After hosting my own email server for 2 years I feel like it has come time to admit defeat. **I can't get my email delivered past spam filters** on Microsoft and Google despite following every protocol, every instruction, and building a clean reputation for my IP and domain over 2 years' worth of time. I am the only user on this domain and I only send personal email, so obviously Microsoft and Google should be marking all of my email as non-spam.

Anyway, **I just want my email delivered**. My question is how to actually do this in practice? In particular, is there a large corporation that I could pay to deliver my emails from my personal domain? I know many places advertise these services, but which of them are actually able to deliver email? Or if someone wants to fix deliverability on my mail server, I'm open towards rechecking everything one more time.

Comment: Your question will probably get closed for being too broad as well as opinion-based.  But in the meanwhile, the most important steps you can take (IMO) are to create an SPF record, and ensure that RDNS lookup is correct for your domain.  But I can't imagine why you think any automated filtering would know or care that you "only send personal email";  there's no real "obviously" behind your conclusions.

Comment: https://glockeasymail.com/email-marketing/how-to-get-emails-delivered/

Comment: @Debra I think an automated spam filtering should notice that a domain is sending very low volume of email, and therefore mark it as non spam. According to glockapps, my SPF record and RDNS are set correctly.

Comment: Works for me.  Use ESMTP, use SPF records, set up correct reverse DNS.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to improve your mail server.

You can use this service : https://www.mail-tester.com/. Send an email, and it will shows you a report with all the problems and some clues to fix them.

If you have already done all possible security improvements, like DKIM, DMARC, reverse DNS and so, maybe you are still grey or black-listed by some antispam lists. I already hadthis issue myself : some companies were using their own mail server with an old antispam blacklist were I was still listed. Some antispam lists grey-lists by default large range of IP just because they are reserved to regular people use and may be used by spammers.

Comment: Mail-tester.com gave me a perfect 10/10 score.